# Change DenyHosts report: Call external command from Python

Tags: python

To begin with, I don't know the first thing about Python ... so I can really use any pointers you have. I do know some Perl, Bash scripting and a bit C++.

I'm running DenyHosts (http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/) which every now and then sends me a message through email that an IP address was added to /etc/deny.hosts. Eg.:

```
Added the following hosts to /etc/hosts.deny:

87.215.133.109 (unknown)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So far so good, but I want to add the country of the IP address to this message. To do this I created a small Perl script that spits out the country:

```
/usr/local/bin/geo-ip.pl --short 87.215.133.109
Netherlands
```

So all I want to do is to call this Perl script from Python and then fill the result in the message string. I located the source code which I suspect I need to change, but as announced at the top of this message, I don't know the first thing about Python.

This is a sniplet from the main program calling a subroutine in report.py

deny_hosts.py:

```
#print deny_hosts
new_denied_hosts, status = self.update_hosts_deny(deny_hosts)
if new_denied_hosts:
    if not status:
        msg = "WARNING: Could not add the following hosts to %s" % self.__prefs.get('HOSTS_DENY')
    else:
        msg = "Added the following hosts to %s" % self.__prefs.get('HOSTS_DENY')
    self.__report.add_section(msg, new_denied_hosts)
    if self.__sync_server: self.sync_add_hosts(new_denied_hosts)
    plugin_deny = self.__prefs.get('PLUGIN_DENY')
    if plugin_deny: plugin.execute(plugin_deny, new_denied_hosts)
```

I think the change should go somewhere in here.
report.py defines the add_section:

```
def add_section(self, message, iterable):
    self.report += "%s:\n\n" % message
    for i in iterable:
        if type(i) in (TupleType, ListType):
            extra = ": %d\n" % i[1]
            i = i[0]
        else:
            extra = ""
        if self.hostname_lookup:
            hostname = self.get_hostname(i)
            debug("get_host: %s", hostname)
        else: hostname = i

        self.report += "%s%s\n" % (hostname, extra)

        if self.use_syslog:
            syslog.syslog("%s - %s%s" %(message, hostname, extra))
    self.report += "\n" + "-" * 70 + "\n"
```

Please help me change the code in such a way that it'll spit out a message like:

```
Added the following hosts to /etc/hosts.deny:

87.215.133.109 (Netherlands, unknown)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**EDIT3:**
This is how I solved it. The output is identical to the original message. After changing the sources, the daemon needs to be restarted (sudo /etc/init.d/denyhosts restart)

```
    def add_section(self, message, iterable):
    # added geo-ip
    # moving this from statement to the top of the file makes pycheck generate
    # a lot of errors, so I left it here.
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
    # end geo-ip hack import
    self.report += "%s:\n\n" % message
    for i in iterable:
        if type(i) in (TupleType, ListType):
            extra = ": %d\n" % i[1]
            i = i[0]
        else:
            extra = ""
        if self.hostname_lookup:
            hostname = self.get_hostname(i)
            debug("get_host: %s", hostname)
        else: hostname = i

        # self.report += "%s%s\n" % (hostname, extra)
        # JPH: added geo-ip
        geocmd = "/usr/local/bin/geo-ip.pl --short %s" % i
        country = Popen( geocmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
        country = country.strip()
        self.report += "%s%s\n%s\n" % (hostname, extra, country)
        # end geo-ip hack            

        if self.use_syslog:
            syslog.syslog("%s - %s%s" %(message, hostname, extra))
    self.report += "\n" + "-" * 70 + "\n"
```

Also help me understand what I change, so I can learn a bit Python today too.

**EDIT2**: For the sake of sharing a link to the geo-ip.pl script http://wirespeed.xs4all.nl/mediawiki/index.php/Geo-ip.pl

**EDIT1**: Recompilation is done automatically when the source changes, so that answers the question below.
The second problem I have with this is that I found two matching files on my system:

- /usr/share/denyhosts/DenyHosts/report.py
- /usr/share/denyhosts/DenyHosts/report.pyc

where the .py is the source code and I suspect .pyc actually being executed. So when I change the source code, I wouldn't be surprised nothing changes if I don't somehow compile it afterwards.

Comment: You don't need to compile the source. The `.pyc` file is a cached byte-code representation that is automatically rebuild when you change and then rerun the script.
You can run an external command with ``os.system``. Btw.

Comment: @AndreasMueller: `os.system` wont let him get the return value.

Comment: I'd love to help you out here, but your question is just all over the place - if all you *really* want to do is execute an external command and store the output in a variable, check out the excellent `subprocess` module. Create a simple script that does only that. Fix it. Then tackle the next problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm only going to answer the specific part of your question about how to call your perl script via python and get the output. The part about where to slot in this info is a little too vague for me to guess from your snippets...

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

hostIP = "87.215.133.109"
cmd = "/usr/local/bin/geo-ip.pl --short %s" % hostIP
output = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]

## alternate form ##
# cmd = ["/usr/local/bin/geo-ip.pl, "--short", hostIP]
# output = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]

print output.strip() 
# Netherlands
```

#### Update

Since I am doing a few things at once on that Popen line, and you are new to python (based on your comments below), I wanted to break down that line a bit for you...

```
# this call to Popen actually returns a 
# Popen object with a number of methods and attributes
# to interact with the process that was just created
p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)

# communicate() is a method of a Popen object which
# allows you to wait for the return output of the pipes
# that you named (or send data to stdin)
# It blocks until data is ready and returns a tuple (stdout, stderr)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

# We only wanted the stdout in this case, so we took the first index
output = p.communicate()[0]

# output is a string, and strings have the strip() method to remove 
# surrounding whitespace
stripped_output = output.strip()
```

Comment: +1 for going the extra mile and showing `Popen`, which is handy for all sorts of cases!

Comment: Can I move the output into a variable? Something like country = output.strip()

Comment: Of course. `output` in this case is the variable. Its a string. I was simply calling the `strip()` method of the string object to remove any surrounding whitespace.

Comment: Can I compare this construction with Perl's $_ that is the default variable to hold output?

Comment: Not really, because its not a default variable. I could have called it anything, and I just chose `output`. Python doesn't have most of those magic perl symbols. I will update my answer to give you a little break down of that Popen command...

Comment: @jippie, no, I don't think so. If I remember correctly, you can avoid using the `$_` in Perl too and just collect output to a variable. That is what @jdi is doing here...

Comment: Ahh ... I see, the update clarifies a lot. I was confused with the 'stdout', I thought 'stdout' related to 'output' but it relates to the catching  the stdout of the cmd being called.

Comment: shouldn't I use rstrip() instead of strip() to remove the newline at the end of the output? Ah wait, just found out what the R stands for. It is basically the same function as strip(), but limited to the right of the string :)

Comment: Do you want to keep whitespace at the head? I figured you wouldn't want any whitespace on the head or tail of the string.

Comment: Keeping fingers crossed ... I made the change, pychecker doesn't report syntax errors. First time I hardly can't wait for the SSH brute force'ers to visit my machine ;o) I'll keep you posted.

Comment: I spoke too soon, I did get two warnings: 'No global (PIPE) found' and 'No global (Popen) found'. They're warnings though.

Comment: That means you didnt inckude the import statement from my example just like you skipped that line in the other answer

Comment: yup ... warnings disappeared. Now you know why I'm not a programmer ;o)

Comment: Although I changed the the code (refer to EDIT3 above), nothing seems to have changed. I removed all .pyc files, just to make sure all byte codes will be recompiled.

Comment: I also added an extra check in my geo-ip.pl script so it doesn't silently die any more when no parameters are passed.

Comment: I dont know. There could be other conditionals in the code and this section may not be getting run? Did you try to place print statements around your additions to find out? Also, move your import to the top of the entire file with the others. Btw this python script is poorly written

Comment: Found another stupidity: denyhosts was running as a daemon, so I restarted that too. When I move the import up to the header of script, pychecker returns a long list of warnings. That's why I put it at the begin of the subroutine definition. Waiting for visitors ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9210/discussion-between-jdi-and-jippie)

Comment: It works now, apart from a formatting error, but I can easily solve that: Spain93.189.94.179 (pixeliastudio.siliconpeople.net)

Comment: Thanks jdi for your patience :)

Answer (score 1):

This could do the trick:

```
import subprocess
country = subprocess.check_output(
    ["/usr/local/bin/geo-ip.pl", "--short", "87.215.133.109"])
```

Comment: *Note: subprocess.check_output() is only available starting with python2.7, just in case he has python2.6

Comment: right. I'm also forever stuck on old python versions. but it *is* a lot less code to write :)

Comment: I'm still trying to break my lazy habit of using the `commands.getstatusoutput`. lol. Its the simpler equiv of  `subprocess.check_output`

Comment: $ python --version
Python 2.7.2+

Comment: Does subprocess require the loading of a module? Do I have to add a line for that? Eg. in Perl loading a module requires a 'use subprocess;' statement.

Comment: I didn't check this solution, but I may work equally well. I had to choose one and I picked the other one. No particular reasoning. Thanks Daren for your explanation.

Comment: @jippie, you did good: jdi went the extra mile and that should be rewarded!